# Can I compute "easily" $\mathbb P (X < t \leq X+Y)$ ($X$,$Y$ two independent RV)?

Tags: probability

Given two independent random variable $X$ and $Y$ both defined on $]-\infty,\infty[$, I am interested to study $\mathbb P (X < t < X+Y)$.

Intuitively I want to say that:
$$
\mathbb P (X < t \leq X+Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \left (\int_{t+x}^{\infty} f_Y(y)dy \right ) f_X(x)dx
$$
but why is this correct (if it is)?

Are there other more straightforward ways to write it for some distributions (such as Normal distributions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take $-x+t$ instead of $x+t$.

Let us consider for that the integration domain and the way it is swept for a given $t$ ; it is explained on the figure below for $t=2$. For this value, the domain can be swept by all half-lines with equations

$x+y=u+t \iff y=-x+u+t$ for any $u > 0$,

these half-lines being limited to vertical line $x=t$.

Remark : One could imagine a different sweeping mode, for example with horizontal segments.

As a consequence your integral should be

$$\iint_{(x,y) \in (-\infty,t] \times [-x+t,\infty)}f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{t} \left (\int_{t-x}^{\infty} f_Y(y)dy \right ) f_X(x)dx$$

[image]

*The domain is this 45° unbounded "wedge" (with vertex at $(t,0)=(2,0)$ in this example) ; here it is swept by half-lines.*

Comment: oups, indeed I made a typo but meant -x+t. 
My question is: how do I come up with the left part of your equation? What allow me to do this (based on the probability I'm computing)? But I guess it's just the definition?

Comment: Saying that $t<x+y$ is equivalent to say that there exist a so-called "slack variable" $u>0$ such that $x+y=t+u$ (this is a classical way to transform an inequality into an equality (you use always this when you do "linear programming"). It is not probability issue.